# Trello card color change

Tags: trello

In Trello, nearly due cards turn a greenish-yellow and past due cards turn dark gray. How do I change the colors of the time notification of the cards?

Answer (score 5):

There is no option to accomplish that yet. That's how they built it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which browser you're using, but I accomplished this using [Stylebot for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en), which allows you to provide custom stylesheets to override a site's default styles.